# Making Google TV into a public kiosk

Tags: android, android-layout, google-tv, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I am working on a project where we have to put a Google TV in a public area.  I am building a custom application for it that should be running all the time.  Basically, we don't want someone to be able to switch out of this specific application.  In a perfect world, people walking by should be able to use a keyboard that comes with the Google TV (Revue).  My question is, is there a way to programmatically lock down the system?  Or do we need to use a special keyboard that only has alphanumeric buttons on it?

Comment: Checking to see if this should go to [android.se] or [su].

Comment: He's looking for a programmatic solution. Off-topic for AE. Non-programmatic solutions are the purview of [android.se].

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert in Google TV,but such a problem can be handled in the mobile by creating a Home application and making that as default.So the user cannot switch out the application.Of course you need to make sure that your app is the default Home app before giving it out to the user(anyways this is your device and not the users). I am not sure whether the Google TV has a home intent.

Comment: Google TV does support custom launcher apps.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, is there a way to diagrammatically lock down the system?

Not without creating your own custom firmware, which at the moment is not possible for Google TV IIRC.

> Or do we need to use a special keyboard that only has alphanumeric buttons on it?

Not only do you need that, but you would have to get one that works with the device (not sure if a standard Bluetooth keyboard will work), and then you will run into problems with missing buttons like BACK and MENU. You *might* be able to engineer around those missing buttons by having adequate navigation in the app to avoid users needing them.